# Multiple jars of same groupId and artifactId in WEB-INF

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I am using maven version 3.5.3 and while building my project, I am getting two versions of **apache commons-lang3** in my WEB-INF (**v3.1 and v3.4**) even when I have explicitly specified v.3.4 in my "**dependency-management**" of my parent pom.xml.

Both have the same groupId and artifactId.

I am confused. Is this expected behavior of maven? Under what circumstances does this happen? I was under the impression that maven resolves all dependencies to only one jar if dependencies have same groupId and artifactId.

Comment: v3.1 is coming by being indirectly referenced from a specific reference. On some IDE you have the possibility to see the entire 'Dependency Hierarchy'. Or through the prompt you can run 'mvn dependency:tree' to see it there is any reference to v3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused. Is this expected behavior of maven? Under what
>   circumstances does this happen? I was under the impression that maven
>   resolves all dependencies to only one jar if dependencies have same
>   groupId and artifactId.

And Maven does.
For a same groupId and a same artifactId, the default behavior of a Maven package goal is packaging only one version of them. Note that if multiple versions are available,  the chosen version by Maven is not really predictable.

I imagine that at a time your build performs a manual copy from the jar into the WEB-INF folder (via a Maven plugin for example), or your pom (or a parent of) specifies an [overlay in the WAR](https://www.google.fr/search?q=overlay%20in%20the%20WAR&oq=overlay%20in%20the%20WAR&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.361j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

The `mvn dependency:tree` command should help you to understand where the distinct versions are referenced or pulled.

Comment: I think the manual copy or overlay could be the issue. Can you point out some cases or plugins which do do that?

Comment: You were right. Maven Surefire Plugin was bringing commons-lang3 version 3.1. Since plugin dependencies are not resolved by dependencyMangement, had to specify the required version in pluginManagement in the parent pom.

Comment: But I am surprise that it is added by a plugin. Maven Surefire  plugin dependencies never have to be included in the packaged component. Please give more detail.

Comment: UPDATE: @davidxxx you were right, it wasn't because of a plugin but a war overlay

Answer (score 1):

I saw this problem several times when builds were done without "clean", i.e. using `package` instead of `clean package`. In this case, you may get a mixture of old and recent builds.

Comment: I always use "clean package" or "clean install". Tried deleting the lib repository and .m2 as well but made no difference.