# Exclude transitive dependency from maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-plugin

I am having a situation where two jars of different versions of apache-commons-lang3 are being packaged in my application WAR even when a single version v3.4 is mentioned in my dependencyManagement.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205469/multiple-jars-of-same-groupid-and-artifactid-in-web-inf).

I explored a little and figured out the wrong jar i.e., v3.1 is coming from maven surefire plugin.

Now, I want to exclude apache-commons-lang3 jar that is coming from maven surefire plugin. However, I tried many ways to force surefire to take the latest jar and bring in v3.4 but I am not able to do so.
Does there exist a way to do the above? That is, exclude a transient jar coming from a maven plugin?

I am trying to build this pom but still it is downloading v3.1.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>bhatinik</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <apache.commons.lang3.version>3.4</apache.commons.lang3.version>
        <maven.surefire.plugin.version>2.19.1</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                            <version>${apache.commons.lang3.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                            <version>${apache.commons.lang3.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <skip>false</skip>
                          <excludes>
                            <exclude>${module.test.excludes}</exclude>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>commons-lang3</excludeArtifactIds>
                          </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                   </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: I bet your assumption is wrong...cause the classpath of plugins and the project are separated furthermore dependencies of plugins will never go into resulting project...(war etc.)..have different versions/groupId etc. means usually some of the transitive dependencies coming into your game...Apart from that I don't understand why have configured plugin dependencies in the example pom ? This does not make sense...

Comment: Do you mean that my assumption "the wrong jar i.e., v3.1 is coming from maven surefire plugin" is wrong?

Comment: Short answer: Yes...just try on command line `mvn dependency:tree` and check the output or best would be to post this here...

Comment: dependency:tree is showing v3.4 only(required version). But v3.1 is still being packaged and used inside the war. Seems like some explicit copy of jars is happening.